# Accessing local servers across network routers

Tags: networking, router

I have recently added a dlink router to my existing network, and connected some computers with it. The existing network uses ip range 192.168.1.x and the new router uses 192.168.0.x. Internet services is accessible on both the networks, but a shared resource or a web server connected to one network is not accessible to the systems of other network.

I googled this issue but I am unable to resolve the issue, please help.

I asked this question earlier in stackoverflow and a guy told me to post it here, so trying out my luck. Someone suggested that I should disable dhcp service of second router and it works a charm, however, sometimes I have to break the link of both networks to avoid cross access and then second network fails due to unavailability of ip addresses.

Is there any way I can set up my networks so that they can work work independently and access services and hosts of each other and I can disable the intercommunication easily without bringing the networks down?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474346/how-to-communicate-hosts-in-different-subnet ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple: just disable the DHCP server on the new router. This means that DHCP requests will pass through your new router, and will be answered by your older router, with an offer in the range 192.168.1.0/24. At this point, all of your DHCP clients will belong to the same network, and thus all local resources will be accessible from all of your pcs, it doesn't matter whether they are plugged into the new or the old router. On some routers, you will find this mode of operation referred to as `DHCP Forwarder`, for obvious reasons.

There is also another solution, which allows you to maintain the two separate networks, but this is both more cumbersome, and unrequested for, if I understand the OP correctly.

Comment: I have already tried disabling dhcp, however, if both networks are getting ip from one router, the second network will break down as soon as i disconnect it from main router. I have to disconnect the networks for some security related issues. Please share the other method.